# How to call speech to text engines like cortana siri from cordova to make my app cross platform?

Tags: cordova, speech-to-text, siri, cortana

I want to develop a mobile app which will use Cortana for Windows phone and Siri for iPhone, but dont want to develop 2 different apps for them. Apache Cordova allows the functionality to develop cross platform apps, but did not find any way to utilize the speech to text engines like Cortana and Siri from it. Any pointers?

Comment: What interaction are you Planning? Cortana and Sirir work very different.

Comment: you can't make use of siri on ios apps

Comment: Well you can send small things like make a appointment from what I read but surly not in the same way than you can use Cortana.